# "Incorrect Signature" by Twitter while update/status using OAuth.js library

Tags: oauth

i get an "Incorrect signature" error by Twitter Api while im posting an update to my twitter account from my app.
I use the javascript OAuth library oauth.js.

Here is my code:

```
consumer.Name =
{ consumerKey   : "xxxxxxxdwcececwscwdc",
  consumerSecret: "xxrtbujztvfdtcehz5tjv6uvjxbzuku7ik",
  serviceProvider:{  
     signatureMethod     : "HMAC-SHA1"
   , requestTokenURL     : "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
   , userAuthorizationURL: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
   , accessTokenURL      : "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
   , echoURL             : "myApp.html"
 }
}
```

`function postTweet(consumerName, twitterText){`

`var accessor = consumer[consumerName];`

```
message = {method: "POST",action: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json", 
parameters:{
   oauth_token: my_oauth_token// <-- here is the current oauth_token
   status: twitterText,
 }
}; // end of message

OAuth.completeRequest(message,
 {
   consumerKey : accessor.consumerKey,
   consumerSecret : accessor.consumerSecret
 }
);



var authorizationHeader = OAuth.getAuthorizationHeader("", message.parameters);
var requestBody = OAuth.formEncode(message.parameters);
var postTweetText = newXMLHttpRequest();
postTweetText.onreadystatechange = function receiveAccessToken(){
if (postTweetText.readyState == 4) {
blabla
}
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
postTweetText.open(message.method, message.action, true);
postTweetText.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

`postTweetText.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);//;`

```
postTweetText.send(requestBody);//requestBody
```

}
}

What am i doing wrong?

}

Comment: Have u got the solution? I'm also facing the same problem with that library actually :(

Answer (score 0):

coming in rather late on this question but hopefully this leads someone with similar issues to a solution.

I had the same response, but it was because I had set up OAuth with a different app, had saved those credentials and then tried posting to a different registered app on Twitter. Hence, an incorrect signature because I was trying to authenticate with a different app's credentials.

Fixed by nuking the binary and doing a clean/build.